# Why i can't get gesture state from array

Tags: ios, nsarray, uigesturerecognizer

In my code i add the gestures to an array. That what i mentioned:

```
- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer{
     [arrayLineGestures addObject:panGestureRecognizer];
     [arrayAllGestures addObject:[arrayLineGestures copy]];

   }
```

So after a time i wanna use them again and i use this code:

```
for (int i=0; i<[arrayAllGestures count]; i++) {
    for (int k=0;k<[[arrayAllGestures objectAtIndex:i]count]; k++) {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer=(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)[[arrayAllGestures objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:k];           
        const CGPoint point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:[panGestureRecognizer locationInView:panGestureRecognizer.view]];
        if (panGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {Nslog(@"began")}
```

But this code doesn't work. It shows the pangesture state as UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible.But before i add them to the array i checked the states no one is UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible. I couldn't see the mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: You question is a bit vague. Where did you check the state before adding to the array ? What is the exact purpose of your doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `state` of any `UIGestureRecognizer` will only be valid for the time you are in your handler. The `panGestureRecognizer` that you are passed in is not a snapshot of state, but rather an object reference to the recognizer. When you store it off in an array and try to reference it later, the `state` isn't valid because the life-cycle of the recognizer has likely expired.

If you iterate through your array, you'll probably find that all of the recognizers are the same object. I don't know if this is guaranteed though, so don't rely on that.